# Basic DOJO 1.8: How to get a reference to a method?

Tags: function, methods, reference, dojo

I'm am pretty new to DOJO 1.8 and would like to know how I can call a function from outside a require-method? I try to implement a message-box which fades in and out.

I created the method:

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!" ], function(dom, on, ready) {

    /*function which shows a msg-box on top of the page */
    var showMsg = function(text) {
        dom.byId("msgbox").innerHTML = text;
    }     
});
```

OK! IT works....but I no I would like to call it from somewhere else in my application:

```
showMsg("Item saved");
```

But that doesn't work: Uncaught ReferenceError: showMsg is not defined

How do I get that reference?

Thank you for your help!

AFX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As things stand you're declaring a local variable and so it's not visible elsewhere in the program.

You could make the variable global, for example

```
window.showMsg = function(text) {
    dom.byId("msgbox").innerHTML = text;
}
```

The downside of this approach is that as you application gets bigger you end up with more and more global variables and that makes maintenance harder.

So Dojo offers ways to package chunks of reusable code and refer to them. You are already exploiting some of those capabilities when you use "require" - you're getting access to chunks of dojo. You can make your own code visible as reusable chunks in the same way.

This is quite a big topic, but you could start by reading [this](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/modules/)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is to move the require inside the function.

Even if you have many such functions, while it's annoying to repeat, there is essentially no runtime penalty for requiring over and over. The only thing to watch for is that code inside the function becomes asynchronous, so instead of returning a value you have to use a callback or promise.

Alternatively, if you're only using this function from within some event handlers (I see `dojo/on`), you can set them up within the scope of this same require block.